# Symfony Logging

Tags: php, logging, symfony1

In Java, I use *log4J* that is a logging framework.  In Log4j you can do something like this:

```
if (log.isDebug()) {
  // do some expensive operation that should only be displayed if DEBUG is turned on
}
```

Reading some Symfony examples, I am unable to find a way to determine if DEBUG logging is activated in the current class context.  Is there a way to do this?

```
if (--need something here--) {
  $this->logMessage('Expensive operation return value: '.expensiveFunction(), 'debug');
}
```

Comment: Alternativly, the log statement can be written as:

$this->getLogger()->debug('Expensive operation return value: '.expensiveFunction());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like

```
$this->getLogger()->getLogLevel() == sfLogger::DEBUG
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks, I will be using this as a guide: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/sfLogger

Answer (score 3):

You should check the usage for [Monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try: `sfConfig::get('sf_logging_enabled').`
It shows if logging is enabled. 
The levels can be configured in the factories.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You can check is in debug mode with that:

```
if ($this->get('kernel')->isDebug()) {
    ...
}
```

This is information about logger service https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/console/logger.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the symfony logger service
if your are in a controller you can call this service using this code:

```
if ($this->get('kernel')->isDebug()) {
 $this->get('logger')->err('my custom message');
}
```

If you want to improve your system yo can check MonologBundle
http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html